# How to generate a range of timestamps in milliseconds for 1 hour?

Tags: python, time

How to generate a range of timestamps in milliseconds for 1 hour?
I want to generate an array / list of timestamp for 1 hour period in milliseconds
ie:
(hh:mm:ss.ms)

00:00:00.0

00:00:00.1

00:00:00.2

00:00:00.3

....

00:59:59.9

01:00:00.0

Comment: what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the idea is to go from 0 to 59 for the minutes/seconds, and from 0 to 9 with the ms. Since the hour is always 0 (except for the last case) you can add it exceptionally in the end.

```
out = []
for minutes in range(60):
    for seconds in range(60):
        for ms in range(10):
            padmin = "0" + str(minutes) if minutes < 10 else str(minutes)
            padsec = "0" + str(seconds) if seconds < 10 else str(seconds)
            timestamp = ":".join(["00", padmin, padsec, str(ms)])
            out.append(timestamp)
out.append("01:00:00:0")
print(out)
```

Comment: Perfectly homework adequate solution :-)

Comment: @gnight, just trying to help..

Comment: @parsleycoriander if it helped you, could you please accept the awnser?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865760/python-how-can-i-create-a-range-of-equally-spaced-timestamps-with-a-resolution/), you could use the following:

```py
# Import the required libraries
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Select your inputs
start_date_string = "14/10/2021 12:00:00.000"    # String
end_date_string = "14/10/2021 13:00:00.000"      # String
frequency = 1000                                 # In Hz

# Convert the strings of dates into the Python datetime format
start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_date_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Create a range of dates
index = pd.date_range(start = start_datetime, end = end_datetime,
                      freq="{}".format(1000/frequency)+"L")
```

Alternatively, at the end you could simply use instead `index = pd.date_range(start = start_datetime, end = end_datetime, freq="L")` because your required resolution of 1 milliseconds fits it.

This will result in what you are after:

```py
DatetimeIndex([       '2021-10-14 12:00:00', '2021-10-14 12:00:00.001000',
               '2021-10-14 12:00:00.002000', '2021-10-14 12:00:00.003000',
               '2021-10-14 12:00:00.004000', '2021-10-14 12:00:00.005000',
               '2021-10-14 12:00:00.006000', '2021-10-14 12:00:00.007000',
               '2021-10-14 12:00:00.008000', '2021-10-14 12:00:00.009000',
               ...
               '2021-10-14 12:59:59.991000', '2021-10-14 12:59:59.992000',
               '2021-10-14 12:59:59.993000', '2021-10-14 12:59:59.994000',
               '2021-10-14 12:59:59.995000', '2021-10-14 12:59:59.996000',
               '2021-10-14 12:59:59.997000', '2021-10-14 12:59:59.998000',
               '2021-10-14 12:59:59.999000',        '2021-10-14 13:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=3600001, freq='L')
```

Finally, you can proceed to transform it into for example a list by using `index.tolist()`.